# Xamarin Visual Studio: GridView with image from url

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, gridview, xamarin, android-gridview

I'm developing portable application with Visual Studio and Plugin of Xamarin
(Xamarin.Forms).

I'm trying create a gridview with images from url, I'm following this example for GridView:

I try replace on ImageAdapter, this following lines:

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/layout/grid_view/create_a_grid_view/

This example work perfectly with images on /resources/drawables but I need download images from url.

```
imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
```

with

```
Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png");
imageView.SetImageURI(url);
```

but don't work.

Please help me.

Comment: Does it show any error message and/or is there anything in the application output (debug window) that indicates the error?. Also make sure you've set [the internet permission for the android project](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/)

Comment: Thank for response, My app has internet permission, and yes show a error message: `02-06 15:02:02.208 E/BitmapFactory( 2116): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` . 
`02-06 15:02:02.208 I/System.out( 2116): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SetImageURI` can only be used with URIs that are specific to the Android operating system. When you give your `imageView` the internet url it will try to find the image on your phone locally using the address u gave it and therefor you get an "No such file or directory" error.

What you need to to is to download the image and then convert to a Android Bitmap using `BitmapFactory`. Then you use `imageView.SetImageBitmap` to set the image.

```
private Bitmap GetBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if(bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
        {
            return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To apply the image to the imageView

```
Bitmap bitmap = GetBitmapFromUrl("http://xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png");
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Ok, this work, but y need `x` photos in gridview, where `x` is a length of `String Array[urls]`. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure it applies in your case but consider using a RecyclerView instead of GridView and use the StaggeredGridLayoutManager to get the images to order nicely in a grid manner much like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYsO_h6I_Hw)

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches work, but is a good practice to do it asynchronously. Here you have some good examples:

1. Asynchronous Image Loading in Xamarin Android http://javatechig.com/xamarin/asynchronous-image-loading-xamarin-android
2. xamarin-store-app image helper https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-store-app/blob/master/XamarinStore.Droid/Helpers/Images.cs

Also here you have a good article about using RecyclerView called "Xamarin Android - A Staggered Grid Layout, via a RecyclerView. And no Java bindings!" http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2015/03/05/xamarin-android-staggered-grid-layout/

Just replace line viewHolder.Thumbnail.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon); of MyRecyclerAdapter.cs for something like this:

- Sync method
  var imageBitmap = Common.GetImageBitmapFromUrl(gridItem.UrlPhoto);
  viewHolder.Thumbnail.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
- Async method (using Image Helper method from xamarin-store-app. Remember to set FileCache.SaveLocation = CacheDir.AbsolutePath; on main activity)
  viewHolder.Thumbnail.SetImageFromUrlAsync(gridItem.UrlPhoto);